# Why does Outlook 2013 not Collapse all my groups when I go to my Inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

In previous versions of Outlook, I clearly remember that when I set my group settings to 'Always Collapse' and if I clicked out of my Inbox (with certain groups expanded), say to my Sent Items, and returned back to my Inbox -- all the groups would be collapsed. This is exactly how I like it -- my folder to reset the groups to 'All Collapsed'

However this does not happen in Outlook 2013. When I come back to a folder, it shows me the last view of that folder, i.e. with some groups expanded, some collapsed, basically just how I left it -- I don't want that. I tried adjusting the settings and thought each time I would return to my Inbox all my groups would be collapsed, but that's just not happening.

[image]

Couldn't find how to do this on the Microsoft site. Would be great if someone could help me out here. Thanks

-Sean

Comment: You can always expand a folder by pressing + on the numeric keypad.  They can be collapsed using - on the numeric keypad.  To expand all folders use * on the numeric keypad.  Don't try the * on heavily nested folders - it will take forever to expand.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of Outlook has changed such that the 'All expanded' or 'All collapsed' groupings are influenced by whether any group is expanded or collapsed. If this is done then the setting is changed to 'As last viewed' since outlook thinks you are making a deliberate change to the settings. To resolve this issue right click on any grouping and choose 'Expand All Groups' or 'Collapse All Groups'. You can now move to another folder group e.g. from Inbox to Sent items. When you return the inbox will be either collapsed or expanded according to your preference.